# How to save messages as Draft

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sms, drafts

I own and Optimus One(Froyo). I want to type some couple of messages(for the same contact) and save it for sending later. How to do that?

EDIT: User wishes to save message templates that can be re-used at a later instance.

Answer (score 2):

For saving drafts, GMail and Email both save drafts automatically when you leave the app or lock the phone. For SMS, it should keep any text you've entered in the text entry field until you send or delete it.

Comment: I suppose it is only the last message. I want to save more than 1 message.

Comment: Are you talking about SMS or email?

Answer (score 1):

In Handcent SMS, you can save commonly used snippets as QuickText

Answer (score 1):

why dont you save message as **Memo** ...You can view anytime you want...
and when you wish to send...simply go to that Memo and tab their for 2 seconds...
It will pop-up **Send-Via**...Choose **Messaging** Option...and then Send...

Comment: @Vizay Soni How do you do that?

Comment: in my galaxy fit/ace plus... i had an option to send memo as sms.. i am not sure other mobiles has these features..